# Is it normal that scatterplot and Anscombe residual plot have same shape, but translated? (linear regression)

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, residuals, scatterplot

I'm using R to produce a scatterplot and a residual (anscombe) plot. However I got something really weird. As you can see below.

Here is the scatter plot:
[image: scatter]
And here is the residual:
[image: residual]

As you can see they have the same exact shape, but they are just moved. Is this normal in a simple linear regression context?

**Code**

I am pretty confident of my code, but anyway, to take away any doubt this is a Minimal Example of my code:

```
# Plot the scatter plot, where x is the explanatory variable, y the response
plot(data$x, data$y)
# Fit linear model
data.lm <- lm( y ~x, data=data)
# Create standardized residuals
data.lm$sr <- rstandard(data.lm)
# Plot the Residual Plot
plot(data.lm$fitted.values, data.lm$sr)
```

**Edit**

Here is the fitted line:

[image: fitted]

Comment: On the contrary, these are *not* "the same exact shape."  Look more closely: in particular, consider what the slope of a well-fitted line would be.

Comment: @whuber Mmm well I fitted the line in R, I can edit the post and put the line there

Comment: @whuber I think I am not understanding your point.. Well yes maybe not exactly, but it seems like the pattern is the same!

Comment: *Of course* it looks similar--these are a dataset with a slight linear trend (in the first instance) *and the very same data* with the linear trend removed.  But they are different, as you could easily ascertain by overlaying the two plots at the same scale.

Comment: @whuber oh okay it makes sense!! I never saw it this way. So the Residual Plot shows you the variability of the response with respect to the linear model?

Comment: @whuber , furthermore, just as a quick question ( I know it's not part of the question here itself), if you see a slight linear trend in the scatterplot, what do you see in the anscombe? Is there evidence of heteroscedasticity?

Comment: No evidence of heteroscedasticity at all.  That's because (a) even the visual suggestion, if any, is slight; (b) there aren't enough data to be confident in assessing differences in variances; and (c) it's easy to be fooled by the impression of smaller variances among sparse data (at the left) compared to more data (at the right).

Comment: @whuber okay thank you! It is just so hard for me to interpret the plots, it seems like every expert has a bunch of "unwritten" theory, which is still obscure to me

Comment: One way to obtain experience with interpretation is through simulation.  Formulate a model; generate data; plot them; repeat. Look at each of the plots, considering how you would interpret them. Then compare your interpretations to what you know to be true. This enables you to learn which aspects matter and which might be superficial and reflect only chance variation. Here's an example: `n <- 27;
alpha <- 20;
beta <- 1/3;
x <- round(runif(n, 20, 55));
par(mfrow=c(3,4));
invisible(replicate(12, {
  y <- round(alpha + beta*x + rnorm(n, 0, 5));
  plot(x,y, pch=19, col="#00006080")
}))`